# Как защитить composer.json и /vendor в production-среде?

Tags: php, безопасность, composer, iis

Вопрос следует сформулировать более широко:
насколько вообще безопасно размещение директория `/vendor` в структуре сайте в production-среде?

То есть сейчас я могу сделать вызов http://mysite.com/composer.json или http://mysite.com/vendor/composer/installed.json и увидеть содержимое файлов.

Допускаю, что кому-то это может облегчить злые намерения. Злоумышленники могут видеть версии используемых библиотек, например, что упростит для них поиски эксплоитов.

Есть ли способ вынести директорий `/vendor` за структуру сайта? Нужно ли (возможно ли) это? Пока я нашел [только одну статью](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192028/is-it-safe-to-have-composer-in-production) на эту тему. Если копнуть глубже, то предлагается запретить доступ к чувствительным файлам на уровне IP-фильтрации.

А есть ли альтернативные способы? Кто и как решает эту задачу в продакшене?

Comment: Ваша основная ошибка - корень сайта совпадает с корнем проекта. Перенесите то, что должно быть доступно на сайте, в подкаталог наподобие public_html и сделайте его корнем сайта, а vendor не переносите - и проблема исчезнет сама собой.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Я на IIS (Windows Server). Все сайты размещены в каталоге `inetpub`. Например: `C:\inetpub\site1` и внутри `site1\vendor`. То есть, в ваших формулировках, да, корень сайта совпадает с корнем проекта (какого проекта? ;-)

Comment: А это ваша вторая ошибка — все сайты размещены в одном каталоге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, вам проект находится в `c:\inetpub\site1.ru`. На примере cakephp структура папок проекта выглядит следующим образом

```
\config
\src
 --\controller
 --\template
\tmp
\vendor
\webroot        -- папка, которая должна играть роль корня сайта
 --\css
 --\img
 --\js
 --\index.php
\composer.json
\index.php
\web.config    -- конфиг для IIS
```

в терминах апача у вашего сайта долженбыть указан document root, папка которая собственна и видна снаружи. Все http-запросы приходят сюда, а вот код, может иметь доступ и к папкам верхнего уровня. Фактически в IIS такой настройки и и нет и корнем является сама папка проекта. Но! `index.php` (в папке сайта) в данном случае имеет одну строку кода

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

а `webconfig` должен настроить перенаправление всего, что приходит, в `webroot`. Правила описываются в разделе

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
```

Далее сначала мы игнорируем прямые запросы к `site.ru/webroot`

```
<rule name="Exclude direct access to webroot/*" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^webroot/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Далее мы рарзрешаем доступ ко вложенным директориям и некоторым файлам, например css, js и т.п.

```
 <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, favicon)" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(img|css|js|fonts|favicon.ico|favicon.png|robots.txt)(.*)$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
```

а все остальные запросы мы перенаправляем в index.php (что в целом справедливо для любого фреймворка)

```
 <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
```

таким образом клиент может обратиться только к содержимому папки `webroot`, и не видит ни composer.json ни vendor и ничего иного, чего ему не положено видеть.

в общем говоря, если вы используете какой-либо фреймворк, то ознакомьтесь с инструкциями по его разворачиванию на IIS, примеры конфигураций должны быть в документации. А если не используете, то возьмите подход, описанный в каком-либо фреймворке и следуйте ему в своем проекте.

Comment: У меня нет слов, чтобы выразить своё восхищение этим ответом. Который, помимо описания самого подхода, содержит еще необходимый мне гайдлайн для IIS'а. Через восемь минут я запустил сайт с обновлённой структурой без лишних "танцев с бубнами". На винде это большая редкость... Спасибо.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown не забудьте включить `opcache` и поставить `wincache` при необходимости для ускорения работы.

Answer (score 4):

Серверному коду в document_root вебсервера вовсе нечего делать. В document_root должен быть `index.php`. И всё, всё остальное здесь не нужно и размещается где-то уровнем выше.

[laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x)

> After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's
>   document / web root to be the public directory. The index.php in this
>   directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests
>   entering your application.

[Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation)

> By setting basic/web as the document root, you also prevent end users
>   from accessing your private application code and sensitive data files
>   that are stored in the sibling directories of basic/web. Denying
>   access to those other folders is a security improvement.

[symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

> The public directory is the home of all of your application's public
>   and static files, including images, stylesheets and JavaScript files.
>   It is also where the front controller (index.php) lives.
>
> The public directory serves as the document root when configuring your
>   web server. In the examples below, the public/ directory will be the
>   document root. This directory is /var/www/project/public/.

Что там ещё из популярного? Уверен что найдёте в документации всё то же самое: document_root вашего веб-сервера должен смотреть куда-то внутрь проекта, но не в корень. Следовательно, вас вовсе никак не волнует что кто-то попытается загрузить что-то. Пусть пытается, для веб-сервера существуют файлы в document_root, где лежит только то что вы сами решили публиковать.

Иначе говоря, нормальная структура проекта:

```
.
.git/
.gitignore
/vendor/
/public/
/public/index.php
composer.json
composer.lock
```

Веб-сервер смотрит строго в `public`.