# Не работает ЧПУ htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Делаю свою страницу на блоге для каждого пользователя. Обработчик - /user.php
В ссылке делаю редирект на ссылку

site.ru/user/?id=123

С помощью .htaccess делаю редирект на site.ru/user.php?id=123

Страница открывается, но нет, ни css, ни js, ни картинок. В чем проблема?

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/? $1.php?id=$2 [L]

# Новый адрес главной страницы
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Перенаправляем с HTTPS на HTTP
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Редирект домена с WWW на домен без WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Убираем лишние слеши на конце URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R=301,L]

# Убираем index.php на конце
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Убираем index.html на конце
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Страницы пользовательских ошибок
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: дак убедитесь, что пути корректные указаны. посмотрите на вкладке Сеть, какой ответ возвращается для этих файлов

Comment: 404. Он не может найти файлы. Сейчас путь site.ru/user/19
Но если саморучно перейти по site.ru/user?id=19, то все корректно находится и отображается

Comment: ну дак а путь к файлам то какой? мб у вас в ссылке там `./css/styles.css` написано, и ничего удивительного в 404 тогда нет.

Comment: Да, действительно. Вопрос таков тогда. Как нужно указывать путь к файлу шапки и подвала? Они вынесены в отдельные файлы. Т.е. Я указываю путь к шапке, как **../header-pad.php**, но внутри шапки присутствуют ссылки на картинки. Что мне делать? Я запутался)

Comment: вы не путайте когда где и что работает. то, как вы подключаете пхп файлы вообще никак не связано с тем, как браузер подключает css и js. Все что вам надо - указать ссылки на подключаемые css-js в виде нормального пути от корня сайта. не `../css/*` и не `./css/*` и даже не `css/*` а `/css/имя-файла.css`. Ваш путь всегда должен начинаться с `/` корня.

Comment: и ознакомьтесь с вопрсом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1033224/223826 по поводу того, какова должна быть структура проекта, что такое корень сайта, и какие там следует хранить файлы и где следует размещать остальные папки а-ля `vendor` и т.п.