# Как в самописном mvc роутере отдавать статику?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc

У меня есть простой mvc роутер

```
class App extends \app\core\Base
{
    //публичные переменные
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->url = $this->parseUrl();
   }
   /**
    * Run the app by calling the controller method and passing it
    * any given params.
    */
   public function dispatch()
   {
       $this->setController();

       $this->setMethod();

       $this->setParams();

       if (class_exists($this->controller)) {
           $controllerObject = new $this->controller();
           if (method_exists($controllerObject, $this->method)) {
               echo call_user_func_array([$controllerObject, $this->method], $this->params);
           } else {
               $this->respondNotFound();
           }
       } else {
           $this->respondNotFound();
       }

   }

   /**
    * Run the app by calling the controller method and passing it
    * any given params.
    */
   public function dispatch()
   {
       $this->setController();

       $this->setMethod();

       $this->setParams();

       if (class_exists($this->controller)) {
           $controllerObject = new $this->controller();
           if (method_exists($controllerObject, $this->method)) {
               echo call_user_func_array([$controllerObject, $this->method], $this->params);
           } else {
               $this->respondNotFound();
           }
       } else {
           $this->respondNotFound();
       }

   }

   /**
    * Parse the url into an array so we can access the indexes as a
    * controller, method and optional params.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   private function parseUrl()
   {
       $requestUri = rtrim(filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER)['REQUEST_URI']);

       if (isset($requestUri) && !empty($requestUri)) {
           return explode('/', str_replace('.php', '', $requestUri));
       }
   }

   /**
    * Set the controller using the first index of the url.
    */
   private function setController()
   {
       array_shift($this->url);

       if (empty($this->url[0])) {
           $this->url[0] = $this->method; // protected $method = 'index';
       }

       $this->url[0] = explode('?', $this->url[0])[0];
       $this->url[0] = ucfirst($this->url[0]);

       $path = str_replace('\\', '/', APP . '/controllers/' . $this->url[0] . 'Controller.php');

       if (file_exists($path)) {
           $this->controller = 'app\\controllers\\' . $this->url[0] . 'Controller';
           unset($this->url[0]);
       }
       else if (!file_exists($path) && !empty($this->url[0])) {
           $this->respondNotFound();
       }

       require_once $path;
   }

   /**
    * Set the method using the second index of the url.
    */
   private function setMethod()
   {
       if (isset($this->url[1]) && method_exists($this->controller, $this->url[1])) {
           $this->method = $this->url[1];
           unset($this->url[1]);
       }
   }

   /**
    * Set the params to pass to the controller method.
    *
    * Params equal the remaining values in the url array rebased.
    *
    * Additionally, we pass the $_POST super global for any optional
    * POST data
    */
   private function setParams()
   {
       $postRequest = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
       $getRequest = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET);

       $this->params = $this->url ? [array_values($this->url), $postRequest, $getRequest] : [$postRequest];
   }
}
```

Далее в index.php

```
use app\core\App;

$app = new App();
$app->dispatch();
```

Для контроллеров и их методов все работает хорошо, но как только доходит дело до попытки подключить какую нибудь статику - все рушится. Пытаюсь покдлючить вот так `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/css/photo.css">` получаю 404 not found. А если подключу вот так `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index/web/css/photo.css">` то получу notice в консоль

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://dummyadmin/photos".
```

Где `"http://dummyadmin/photos"` должен быть css файл, но он редиректит на контроллер. Я попробовал через htaccess создать ограничение, вот так:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|images)
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ files/images/$1 [L]
#другие правила  дальше
```

но это не помогло, я ожидал, что apache благодаря этим правилам не будет обрабатывать js/css и т.д файлы через php скрипты, а вернет их как есть, но видимо, неправильно понял смысл этих правил для htaccess.

Как правильно отдавать статику в таком случае? Где я ошибся?

P.s сейчас статику использую вот так, ввиду отсутствия альтернатив

```
<style>
     <?= file_get_contents(PROJECT . '/web/css/photo.css'); ?>
</style>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` в помощь

Comment: и почему вы вообще подключаете файлы как `/web/css/...` а не `/css/....` ? в хтаксессе то у вас именно такая проверка

Comment: вообще, поразмыслите о структуре папок сайта. у вас корень сайта должен быть в `web`. Используйте так же симлинки для директорий картинок и т.п. при необходимости. Вопрос вообще не о самописном  роутере, а об адекватной структуре проекта и хтаксессе. Роутер к вопросу вообще не относится, поскольку управление ему и не должно передаваться, эти сведения тут избыточны. лучше удалите часть про роутер и привидите структуру файлов и папок проекта, с указанием, где у вас вэбрут

Comment: @teran `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` также не помог, ошибка прежняя, даже с учетом исправления, которое Вы предложили. А про структуру папок немного не понял, иметь index.php не в web порочная практика или это и вызывает ошибки?

Comment: дак  и не поможет, пока вы начинаете ссылки с `/web/...`

Comment: @teran я проверил уже с учетом этого исправления

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1033224/223826 вот вопрос, затрагивающий структуру проектов, ознакомьтесь со всеми ответами.